# firebase database set method appending to array instead of replacing the elements

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase database to store a complex data structure, it looks like this:

```
../thousand_island/
    genomes:[
      0:{
        "somthing": "some content"
      },
      ... 49 more
    ],
    version: 1223
```

The genomes array always have 50 elements. Every time I call `set` to replace all the data in `/my_record_name` then 50 new records will be inserted into the `genomes` array instead of replacing.

[image]

Code sample:

```
// set the ref into the instance
this.ref= firebase.database.ref('/genomes/thousand_island');
...
// record = { genomes:[...], version: *** }
if(version> record.version){
 this.ref.set(record,function(){
   console.log('updated thousand_island ', version, '->', record.version);
 })
}
```

So how to make it replace it instead of appending to the array? I was thinking of deleting the data then insert again but it sounds tedious and it costs 2 requests.

Comment: Can you provide the code that is doing the set? Because `set` definitely replaces all data at the current node.

Comment: Also show the actual database structure instead of what it looks like. Because arrays don't exist in firebase

Comment: @MichaelBleigh sure, I've updated